# minikube error in minikube installed Ubuntu16.04 VM in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, cloud, virtualbox, minikube

I have installed minikube in ubuntu VM in oracle virtualbox. I ran **$minikube start** command. But it is showing error as: "Unable to pick default driver. No possible driver was detected."

Answer (score 0):

While starting a minikube cluster you have to [specify a vm driver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#specifying-the-vm-driver) that will be used to run Kubernetes in. You can do it by using `minikube start --driver virtualbox`.

You can set up default driver by using `minikube config set driver virtualbox`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I need to first install driver virtualbox. Then the commands shown above will run.